# How to embed a page into iframe in extjs

Tags: iframe, extjs5

I am using extjs, and the requirement is to embed a page into an existing site.

I want to create a new tag in ext panel, and then load the page when the user switches to such tag. How would this be done?

Version I am using is extjs 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Extjs js class like below:

```
Ext.define("xxx.xxx.xxx.classname",{
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
alias: 'if need',
controller: "if need",
viewModel: {
    type: "if need"
},
uses: ['if need'],
title: 'if need',
config: {
    xxx: yyy
},
initComponent: function() {

    var me = this;

    var dr = Ext.create('XXX', {
        ...
    });     

    me.items = [dr,{
        region : 'center',
        xtype : "component",
        autoEl : {
            tag : "iframe",
            src : "http(s)://url you need"
        }

    }];

    this.callParent(arguments);

},
```

});

Then create and use this instance in your tag page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Ext.Component, with tag parameter set to 'iframe' and src attribute set to the desired URL. See here more details: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/?mobile=/api/Ext.Component